# div grow at top of screen, shrink once scrolled

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have I top-corner triangle button on my website fixed to the top-right. I want it to animate larger in size (from the top right) by 125% when user is at top of the screen, but return to its regular size when scrolling.

HTML (using font-awesome 'fa fa-home fa-2x' for the icon)

```
<a id="corner-tri" href="#" target="_blank">
    <div id="corner-tri-content">
        <span class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></span>
    </div>
</a>
```

CSS

```
#corner-tri {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999;
  width: 65px; height: 65px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 65px 65px 0; /* adjust for size of triangle */
  border-color: transparent #1ebeaf transparent transparent; /* adjust for color of triangle */
  top: 0; right: 0;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: border-color 0.3s ease;
  transition: border-color 0.3s ease;
}

#corner-tri:hover {
  border-color: transparent #2e2e2e transparent transparent;
}

#corner-tri-content{
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  right: -35px;
}
```

It is current at the size I want it to be when user scrolls, no sure how to animate it larger (125% from top right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things, one, you need your transitions to be for "width"; then, use JQuery (im assuming you can) to catch when the user scrolls.
For example,

in your css, add `#corner-tri {transition: width 1s;}`

in your javascript, add something like this

```
    $("body").scroll(function(){
                           $("corner-tri").css("width",
                                               "[some small width]");
                           return false;
                                };
```

Comment: Yes I have JQuery setup, can i put that in my <head> tags in script tags? and just a simple number ex. [100] in the 'some small width' part

Comment: You need to put it in a function called when the document, or window or body loads; $(window).load(function(){[put it here]}; because you want to make sure the scroll method is binded to body after body actually exists, if you simply put it in the header, body will not exists

Comment: can't seem to get it to work, I added width to the transition. and 100px to the width part of the code

Comment: oops! add "#" to the element ID; `$("#corner-tri")`